# Load an image on specific date and time in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

My question is: how do I load a specific image on a specific date and time in iOS?

I have searched the net but did not find anything useful.

I have a list of images in an imageArray and want every image to be shown on a specific date, time and order.

Fx. say I want to load MyImage on MyDateAndTime. How can I do this?

Image 1 - DateAndTime 1
Image 2 - DateAndTime 2
Image 3 - DateAndTime 3

Any suggestions is appreciated, please provide some source code if possible.

Comment: Give more details. What would you like to do exactly?

Comment: I just want to make a demo-app demonstrating how to load a different image on different dates and times.

Comment: So you have a datbase of images or...? I guess you could created some kind of hash fom date and randomly choose the image

Comment: Exactly, but the image has to be specific as well as the date and time.

Comment: So, I prefer creating additional field in database with assigned data for image and if data is equal to this one in db you show the image.

Comment: You need some kind of map of date-ranges and images. There's no built-in container for this problem, though. It can be solved with a database which has three columns, "start_date", "end_date", and "URL", together with a corresponding query.

Comment: The simple answer is compare the current date to all the dates that may display something different. If any are true, carry out with the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put simple logic, edit it as per your requirement otherwise if you have any query related to my answer then please tells to me.

Best way is store your image with Name of dateTime *(`dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss`)* and access image  name such like,

```
NSString *imageName
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss"];
imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]]; // here you can set specific dateTime, i putted current dateTime
```

Here you get `imageName` such like **19_10_2013_6_13_21.png**

And by this image name you can get image from bundle or document directory.

Comment: Thank you very much I am sure this will work!

Comment: But you are aware, that this requires 3600 images for a date in a range of one hour?

Comment: It would be better to retrieve the date component as the index for your array.

Comment: If people would scroll over the upvote arrow it says "This answer is useful?" which it is, so i don't see why people are down voting this, even if they do not agree it's right, the answer is still useful, +1

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to show a different image every minute, use this, otherwise skip below to see helpful date information.

```
NSTimeInterval secondsInMinute = 60;
[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:secondsInMinute target:self selector:@selector(minuteChanged:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void)minuteChanged:(id)sender {
    // change image here
}
```

You question could have many different answers, do you want to create this date dynamically? or is it a a predefined date? One solution is to get get the timeInterval of the date you are looking for.

```
NSDate* rightNow = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [rightNow timeIntervalSince1970];

// since time intervals are in seconds we can just append the
// date as easily as adding time

NSInteger secondsInMinute = 60;
NSInteger minutesInHour = 60;
NSInteger hoursInDay = 24;
NSInteger daysInWeek = 7;

NSInteger secondsInWeek = secondsInMinute * minutesInHour * hoursInDay * daysInWeek;

timeInterval = timeInterval + secondsInWeek;
NSDate* aWeekInFuture = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];
```

that i would say is the easiest to under stand to set a date, but you could also use components to set a future date dynamically. This leads into some problems but here is how it's done.

```
NSDate* rightNow = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* dateCompenents = [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:rightNow];

[dateCompenents setDay:dateCompenents.day + 7];

NSDate* aWeekInFuture = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateCompenents];
```

to help explain this, here is some console logs

```
(lldb) po rightNow
$0 = 0x0b933440 2013-10-19 12:43:55 +0000
(lldb) po aWeekInFuture
$1 = 0x0ba32a60 2013-10-26 04:00:00 +0000
```

you see how the date is accurate for the day, year, month, but look at the exact time, the current time (right now) is 12:43:55 but the week in he future is 4:00:00 this is because i did not ask for the NSMinutesCalendarUnit, NSHoursCalendarUnit, NSSecondsCalendarUnit... so if i wanted a perfect date that would be inadequate unless i ask for every single thing, but you specifically may not need to be so accurate in fact you may even want to set your own time.

Now if you want a static date, a date the user enters, you will need to use `NSDateFormatter` example below

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setCalendar:currentCalendar];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm/dd/yyyy"];

NSDate* birthdayDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"10/05/2013"];
```

Now you wanted to know how would you know if today is the specified date that is saved. Lets say you stored the date in `NSUserDefaults` or on a server or some place, the easiest way to compare the dates is with the compare function of an `NSDate`

```
NSDate* rightNow = [NSDate date];
NSDate* storedDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey@"storedDate"] // some date from server, or UserDefaults

NSComparisonResult = [rightNow compare:storedDate];
```

this is a bit inadequate since it test for perfection but it will return values of `NSOrderedSame` if they are equal, `NSOrderedDescending` if storedDate is behind rightNow, and `NSOrderedAscending` if storedDate is in front of rightNow. This is all specific down to the time interval. If you just want a generic day, you will have to test it via components

```
NSDate* rightNow = [NSDate date];
NSDate* birthdayDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey@"birthday"]

NSDateComponents* todayComponents = [currentCalendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit) fromDate:rightNow];
NSDateComponents* birthdayComponents = [currentCalendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit) fromDate:birthdayDate];

BOOL dayIsTheSame = ( todayComponents.day == birthdayComponents.day );
BOOL monthIsTheSame = ( todayComponents.month == birthdayComponents.month );

BOOL todayIsBirthday = ( dayIsTheSame && monthIsTheSame );

if (todayIsBirthday) {
    [self.imgViewBirthday setImage[UIImage imageNamed:@"cake.png"]];
}
```

In your question you specified an array of images, lets say you have a different image depending on which hour it is, or which minute, you would use the component, todayComponent.minute after asking for the `NSMinutesCalendarUnit` as the index of this array;

```
UIImage* currentImageToDisplay = [self.arrayOfImage objectAtIndex:todayComponent.minute];
self.imageView.image = currentImageToDisplay;
```

References:
[NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html), 
[NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html), 
[NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html), 
[NSCalendar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html),
[NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

Comment: Also very useful answer - the date is predefined

Comment: dates were always a pain in the ass for any language i use :/ , so this was a good thing for me to look it all up. I mostly use stack overflow for learning purposes, i look for questions that i think i could find the answer for, look up the answer, then reveal my findings . So this is a good question for learning purposes :p

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem now, one fancy approach using a *recursive block* you might check out is this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <dispatch/dispatch.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSArray* dates = @[@1, @1, @1, @1, @1, @1, @1, @1, @1];
        NSArray* urls = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I"];

        NSEnumerator* dateIter = [dates objectEnumerator];
        NSEnumerator* urlIter = [urls objectEnumerator];

        typedef void(^block_t)(NSEnumerator* dateIter, NSEnumerator* urlIter);

        block_t asyncFunc;
        __block __weak block_t _asyncFunc = asyncFunc = ^(NSEnumerator* dateIter, NSEnumerator* urlIter) {
            NSNumber* date = [dateIter nextObject];
            NSString* url = [urlIter nextObject];
            if (date != nil && url != nil) {
                double delayInSeconds = [date doubleValue];
                dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
                dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^(void){
                    NSLog(@"%@", url);
                    _asyncFunc(dateIter, urlIter);
                });
            }
            else {
                printf("\n");
                return;
            }
        };

        // start:
        asyncFunc(dateIter, urlIter);

        sleep (10);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Note:**

The "dates" are actually "delays" and the URLs are actually just strings in this example. You should be able to adjust this as you like. Of course, `NSLog(@"%@", url);` would actually display your image.

Also, the block *asyncFunc* is asynchronous!